# MongoDB aggregate group by multiple fields

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, pymongo

Example documents

```
{
    "user_id": "1",
    "key": "key1"
},
{
    "user_id": "1",
    "key": "key2"
},
{
    "user_id": "2",
    "key": "key1"
},
{
    "user_id": "2",
    "key": "key1"
},
{
    "user_id": "3",
    "key": "key2"
},
{
    "user_id": "4",
    "key": "key1"
}
```

If I want to group by only the `key` field, I can use the query below.

```
db.test.aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
            _id: {
                "key": $key"
            },
            count: {
                $sum: 1
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $sort: {"count":-1}
    },
])
```

It will group by `key` and sort with count of `key`.

However, as you can see from the above documents, there are cases where a single user has a duplicate key.

Therefore, I have to group by with `user_id` field as the target.

Expected data:

```
{"key": "key1", "count": 3}
{"key": "key2", "count": 2}
```

How can I group by with multiple fields?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you clarify a little more. You want to count unique users "user_id" for each "key"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `$group` by `key` and construct the array os unique `user_id` by `$addToSet` operator
- `$size` to get total elements in `user_id`

```
db.test.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$key",
      count: { $addToSet: "$user_id" }
    }
  },
  { $addFields: { count: { $size: "$count" } } },
  { $sort: { count: -1 } }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ChIqFvbYK_Y)

---

The second possible way to understand the `$group` stage,

- `$group` by  both fields `key` and `user_id`
- `$group` by the only key and get a sum of the count

```
db.test.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        key: "$key",
        user_id: "$user_id"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id.key",
      count: { $sum: 1 }
    }
  },
  { $sort: { count: -1 } }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/mebR26KQv5v)